# How can I determine which filter in my DirectShow filter graph failed when I call IMediaControlRun?

Tags: delphi, filter, directshow, hresult

I have a Delphi 6 application using the DSPACK component library that builds a filter graph and then runs it.  When I run the Filter Graph I am getting an error via a *failed* HRESULT return from IMediaControl.Run(), using a cePlay control event status.  I know that I can use the HRESULT error code to guess which filter failed, but I would like a better way.  Is there a way to ferret out which filter triggered the failure when IMediaControl.Run(csPlay) returns a *failed* HRESULT code, via a DirectShow call or sequence of calls?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to know, you are only forwarded the error code from some filter. The best strategy to toubleshoot is to simplify the graph and isolate the problem.

Comment: Ok, will do.  It was easy to track down in this case.  I simply neglected to set the output file name to a file writer filter that needed it assigned before working properly.  But I'm sure there will be other times where the debugging path is not so simple.